# Integrating widgets in android application

Tags: android, widget

I have an application: one frame showing text, second video. I wanted a third frame to show any widget. Is this possible? If, how?

Comment: Can you be more descriptive!!

Comment: make a page for each and every activity and jump one activity to second activity by intent

Answer (score 0):

first of all you have to make widget layout,java and manifest.xml entry.

Then you have integrate your app and widget.

[How to create android app with app widget in single application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15038385/how-to-create-android-app-with-app-widget-in-single-application)

This link is useful for you and if any query then put comment.