# How to create android app with app widget in single application

Tags: android-layout, android-widget, android-activity

I have already done one **android application** which stores date with person name and phone number.

Now I have to develop one **widget** for this application to show today's (date, person name, and phone number) with button.

**Requirements:**

1. Single application with app and widget.
2. When I click on a button which is in the widget, it will start my
   application.
3. Widget data should always synchronize with my app - when today's
   day (person 5 and application add 5 more person then widget display
   10 person data)
4. How can I design this widget? Any guidelines? I have to use
   horizontal ScrollView.

I have done a simple widget demo but I don't know how to synchronize it with my application.

Please share your experience and give some idea about my widget and application.

Comment: I finding entire day to solve first and second requirement and that done.

Comment: http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidWidgets/article.html see this link

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I am finding couple of days I got somehow the solution. So I am sharing my idea.

This site has been very useful for me.

http://kasperholtze.com/android/how-to-make-a-simple-android-widget/

I made some changes and did my work.

**Requirement solution:**

**1.**  Make Receiver and put into manifest permission like this.

```xml
<receiver
        android:name=".WatchWidget"
        android:label="WatchWidget" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.appwidget.action.APPWIDGET_UPDATE" />
        </intent-filter>
        <meta-data
            android:name="android.appwidget.provider"
            android:resource="@xml/watch_widget_provider" />
    </receiver>
```

**2.** In my side require top TextView click so can make using TextView id in `onUpdate()`.

```java
    remoteViews = new RemoteViews(context.getPackageName(),R.layout.widget_lay);

    Intent intent = new Intent(context, TestActivity.class);
    intent.setAction("callActivity");
    PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0, intent, 0);
    remoteViews.setOnClickPendingIntent(R.id.widget_textview, pendingIntent); 
    appWidgetManager.updateAppWidget(new ComponentName(context,WatchWidget.class), remoteViews);
```

**3.** I want to call database and fetch record and display it. Now question what about update?

So I have used timer class and run every 1000sec because of over widget is always update 30min(may be).

```java
@Override
public void onUpdate( final Context context, final AppWidgetManager appWidgetManager, final int[] appWidgetIds )
{

    this.appWidgetManager = appWidgetManager;
    try {
        Timer timer = new Timer();
        timer.scheduleAtFixedRate(new MyTime(context, appWidgetManager,appWidgetIds), 1, 1000);

    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println("Exception:");
    }
    updateSwitch1(context, appWidgetManager, appWidgetIds[0]);

}
```

If any have queries then put a comment and thanks to all who gave me full support to make this answer useful.

Comment: hai i post one question for this link please help me http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18376263/automatically-update-widget-in-the-home-screen-when-i-make-modification-in-my-ap

Comment: The tutorial link gives 500 Internal Server Error.

Answer (score 36):

**Create and configure widget**

> To register a widget you create a BroadcastReceiver with an intent filter for the android.appwidget.action.APPWIDGET_UPDATE action.

```xml
<receiver
       android:icon="@drawable/icon"
       android:label="Example Widget"
       android:name="MyWidgetProvider" >
       <intent-filter >
            <action android:name="android.appwidget.action.APPWIDGET_UPDATE" />
       </intent-filter>

       <meta-data
          android:name="android.appwidget.provider"
          android:resource="@xml/widget_info" />
</receiver>
```

You also specify the meta-data for the widget via the android:name="android.appwidget.provider attribute. The configuration file referred by this meta-data contains the configuration settings for the widget. If contains for example the update interface, the size and the initial layout of the widget.

Create a new file myshape.xml in the /res/drawable directory. This file will define the background we use in your widget.

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
           android:shape="rectangle" >

    <stroke
        android:width="2dp"
        android:color="#FFFFFFFF" />

    <gradient
        android:angle="225"
        android:endColor="#DD2ECCFA"
        android:startColor="#DD000000" />

    <corners
        android:bottomLeftRadius="7dp"
        android:bottomRightRadius="7dp"
        android:topLeftRadius="7dp"
        android:topRightRadius="7dp" />

</shape>
```

Define the following `widget_layout.xml` file under the res/layout folder.

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
          android:id="@+id/layout"
          android:layout_width="match_parent"
          android:layout_height="match_parent"
          android:layout_margin="8dip"
          android:background="@drawable/myshape" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/update"
            style="@android:style/TextAppearance.Medium"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:gravity="center_horizontal|center_vertical"
            android:layout_margin="4dip"
            android:text="Static Text" >
        </TextView>

    </LinearLayout>
```

now make the class.

```java
public class MyWidgetProvider extends AppWidgetProvider {

  private static final String ACTION_CLICK = "ACTION_CLICK";  

     @Override
  public void onUpdate(Context context, AppWidgetManager appWidgetManager, int[] appWidgetIds) {

    // Get all ids
    ComponentName thisWidget = new ComponentName(context,
        MyWidgetProvider.class);
    int[] allWidgetIds = appWidgetManager.getAppWidgetIds(thisWidget);
    for (int widgetId : allWidgetIds) {
      // Create some random data
      int number = (new Random().nextInt(100));

      RemoteViews remoteViews = new RemoteViews(context.getPackageName(),
          R.layout.widget_layout);
      Log.w("WidgetExample", String.valueOf(number));
      // Set the text
      remoteViews.setTextViewText(R.id.update, String.valueOf(number));

      // Register an onClickListener
      Intent intent = new Intent(context, MyWidgetProvider.class);

      intent.setAction(AppWidgetManager.ACTION_APPWIDGET_UPDATE);
      intent.putExtra(AppWidgetManager.EXTRA_APPWIDGET_IDS, appWidgetIds);

      PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context,
          0, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
      remoteViews.setOnClickPendingIntent(R.id.update, pendingIntent);
      appWidgetManager.updateAppWidget(widgetId, remoteViews);
    }
  }
```

Comment: you forgot abtout xml/widget_info file, something like:

`<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<appwidget-provider xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:initialLayout="@layout/widget_layout"
    android:minHeight="146dp"
    android:minWidth="146dp"
    android:updatePeriodMillis="1000000"/>`